# I have to find an average lines for this contour obtained

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a radiograph of a metal piece(cross-sectional view in square shape), I have to find the surface roughness of the metal piece by processing the image.

[image: Original Radiograph]

For this I found the contour for the image, now I have to find an average straight line for each side and find the deviation from the straight line to find the surface roughness

[image: Contour drawn above the radiograph]

Comment: Can you make a sketch for what you mean by a straight line for each side ? The bounding box of your contour ? And what deviation ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.